# Can multiple if conditions having AND OR NOT checks into it be replaced with any other more optimised code JAVA

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

In my code there are number of If(s) without else conditions (really else not required) but I think should there be any other code which has much efficiency than multiple if(s). FYI my if are like if(Some And Or NOTs) if(conditions AND OR NOTS) ...?

Please help to optimize the code as it has increased to much huge volume?

Comment: Could you post example of your code?

Comment: Just write clear code: don't try to be "smart": http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/devinsight_1/

Comment: I wouldn't call `Nested Ifs` unoptimized code.

Comment: @BartKiers HOW CAN I MAKE SURE MY APP IS NOT TAKING TOO MUCH OF EXTRA TIME AND REDUCING THE PERFORMANCEs as there are multiple and or nots in If condition.

Comment: @LondonDreams, by profiling your app, not by worrying about the things you mention in your OP. Please take the time to read the link I posted.

Comment: Whatever you decide to do to your code, make sure you benchmark it to see if you actually gain anything. There's no point in making code less readable if it isn't going to speed it up.

Comment: The answer depends on the nature of what you're actually doing. Performance is unlikely to be a real concern, unless the conditionals include long-running methods. Make clarity your first goal, it will often lead you to a better solution.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234458/do-polymorphism-or-conditionals-promote-better-design] is quite more clearing concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling application is in my opinion the best answer to decide whether the code needs to optimized. It always has a two way answer too much optimizing even may cause performance loss and keep it simple make the code much readable and even optimized according to line of codes.

Answer (score 2):

replace Conditional with Polymorphism
 - < refactoring , improving the design of existing code> ,write by martin fowler

Comment: can u pls add few lines of hint here ?

Comment: search web for 'replace Conditional with Polymorphism'

Comment: The answer is poorly written, but it's still good advice. +1 to balance the downvotes

Comment: Agreed. If you look around there are some threads here on SO which illustrate the point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234458/do-polymorphism-or-conditionals-promote-better-design

Comment: Also check out [this previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786358/get-rid-of-ugly-if-statements/3788488#3788488) (including all up/downvotes and furious discussions and even [a guest appearance in DailyWTF](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/p/20192/234306.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you tried this already, but can you group your if statements into meaningful functions?could prevent code duplication, and sometimes for small stuff it's better then Polymorphism.

for example if you have:

```
Girl shirly;
Girl ruth;
if(shirly.pretty && shirly.smart && (!shirly.married)){
   ...
}
if(ruth.pretty && ruth.smart && (!ruth.married)){
   ...
}

//a better way will be
if(doILove(shirly)){
...
}
if(doILove(ruth)){
...
}
//or in case of a more general statment
if(doLoveCondition(shirly.pretty,shirly.smart,!shirly.married){
...
}
if(doLoveCondition(ruth.pretty,ruth.smart,!ruth.married){
...
}
```

if you would have posted the code, it would have been easier to find a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the switch statement.

Comment: Quote from java tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html): A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types.
It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings)